# Why does Python str.len() see a certain cell in my Pandas object to be 6889, but SQL SERVER len and NOTEPAD++ displays 8002?

Tags: python, jupyter, sqlbulkcopy

I'm using Python to parse a large XML file that we were able to acquire from a 3rd party vendor and i have a predetermined destination table that the length is varchar(8000). I have a logical check within my Jupyter notebook that if the length of a Pandas cell is over 8000, i split it, else just allow it to pass through.

Now, when i trying to do a bulk insert with the CSV output from the Jupyter notebook, I'm getting truncation errors, when i looked into it, a specific row, when doing an df["column"].str.len() returns a length of 6889, but when the exact string, copied and pasted into SSMS and NOTEPAD++, returns 8002, which of course is more than the varchar(8000) field size.

Im trying to look for specific parameters to the str.len() in Python/ Pandas but can't seem to find any, can anyone please explain why?

Thank you and more power!

Comment: "the exact string, copied and pasted into SSMS and NOTEPAD++, returns 8002" I don't understand what this means. What is SSMS? How are you getting Notepad++ to give you a length number?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with smaller data and a smaller database field?

Comment: Karl Knetchel  , in NOTEPAD++, at the bottom right, you will see Ln: X Col: Y , by hovering the cursor at the ver end of the long string, i see 8002. SSMS is SQL Management studio, i enclose it with single quotes and do a len function, also returns 8002. So 2 different applications returning 8002, Python + Pandas str.len() returning 6889.

Comment: "Can you reproduce the problem with smaller data and a smaller database field?", ill try

Comment: newline characters in SQL and notepad++ count as two characters, `\n\r` while in python they are a single character. It is possible that your string has many of these since it is so long. That would be a good place to start checking.

Comment: When I paste it in NOTEPAD++, it is one long line, therefore no carriage returns, but I think it has something to do with special characters. Thank you.